# Regex to Identify Try-Catch and Try-Catch finally blocks contained in a .cs file

Tags: c#, .net, regex, io

Hi I am trying to create an App to help me switch out the test contents of my Catch-Block and replace them with production contents. I am able to read through my file, and parse the contents, but having problems creating a regex( I am brand new to this still) to identify the try-catch block, so I can either choose to delete or change the contents of the catch block. Anyone able to help me solve this problem please??

so far I have the expression below(does not work at all)

```
try{*}catch(*){*)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you also post some of the C# code you're using to delete/replace the contents?

Comment: I have yet to put that part together. I am stuck on identifying the try-Catch or try-Catch Finally in the text file. I read the try-catches into a queue. Then I loop through the queue to make sure that the content is really valid. Since I have not gotten the regex right, I am stuck there.

Answer (score 3):

You can't write a regex that does this, because regex [can't be used to match nested patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns).  Which means that it won't be able to identify when your closing brace occurs vs other nested braces in your code.  You will need a parser generator such as ANTLR like the linked answer suggests to accomplish this.

Comment: I remember from Automata class, I learned how to parse open and closing braces in a file. I figured since that can be done, then it should be possible to use a regex to do something like that. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Regexes can't keep a count of how many open braces vs close braces they have seen, so they aren't suitable for that task.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest taking a look at Microsoft's [Roslyn compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) that is under development. It's APIs should probably allow you to accomplish whatever it is you're looking to do. It is currently in preview.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would drive you to a solution:

```
try\s*\{[^{}]*([^{}]*\{[^{}]*\}[^{}]*)*[^{}]*\}\s*catch\s*\([^()]*(\([^()]*\))*\)\s*\{[^{}]*([^{}]*\{[^{}]*\}[^{}]*)*[^{}]*\}
```

`try\s*` matches try followed by zero or more spaces.

`\{[^{}]*([^{}]*\{[^{}]*\}[^{}]*)*[^{}]*\}` matches a block (`{` followed by zero or more characters except { and } followed by zero or more blocks with any number of characters preceding and succeeding each)

`\s*catch\s*\([^()]*(\([^()]*\))*\)` matches zero or more spaces preceding and following `catch`, then something inside brackets `()`

`\s*\{[^{}]*([^{}]*\{[^{}]*\}[^{}]*)*[^{}]*\}` similar to try block

**Note:** May fail in case of ones with comments containing `{`s or `}`s